# ion-datetime not binding ngmodel

Tags: validation, ionic2

hi everybody this thing is driving me crazy.

I have this code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="search()" #rosterSearchForm="ngForm">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list inset>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime type="text" placeholder="Year" displayFormat="YYYY" name="year" [(ngModel)]="data.rq.Year" required></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-datetime type="text" placeholder="Month" displayFormat="MM" name="month" [(ngModel)]="data.rq.Month" required></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row> 
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="signup-col">
      <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="submit" [disabled]="!rosterSearchForm.form.valid" >Search</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</form>
```

The first date picker does the binding with the ngmodel.
The second one doesnt.
I need to get the year and the month, separately, as text (e.g. "2017" and "11").
The validation always fails as well and the submit button never goes active.

It seems something so simple. But I can't see the error.
I'm going crazy. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
<ion-label stacked>Month</ion-label>
<ion-datetime placeholder="Month"
              pickerFormat="MMM YYYY" 
              displayFormat="MMM YYYY"
              [(ngModel)]="month">
</ion-datetime>
```

and in .ts file

```
this.Year = this.datepipe.transform(this.month,'yyyy')
this.Month = this.datepipe.transform(this.month,'MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do using `ion-datetime` because its not supported. You can use following code:

```
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-list inset>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-datetime type="text"
                          placeholder="Select Month And year"
                          displayFormat="MM/YYYY"
                          pickerFormat="MM YYYY"
                          name="month"
                          [(ngModel)]="rosterSearchForm.month" required>
            </ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="signup-col">
        <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="submit"
                [disabled]="!rosterSearchForm.form.valid" >Search</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
```

and `.ts`

```
  search(rosterSearchForm){

    console.log(rosterSearchForm.value);

  }
```